# VBA Ubound() doesn't work?

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I'm trying to make my own function in VBA-Excel 2010 to count some things in array passed as function arg. Also 2 conditions are passed too. The problem is I can't get Ubound() function to work.

Here's the code:

```
Function IleGier(Arr As Variant, Champ As String, Data As Date) As Variant 'Integer
    '                arr/\           cond1/\        cond2/\
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ile As Integer

    ile = -1
    i = 1

    Do While i < UBound(Arr, 1)
        If Arr(1)(i) = Data Then
            If Arr(2)(i) = Champ Then
                ile = ile + 1
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    IleGier = ile
    'IleGier = Arr(2)(1)
End Function
```

Array will always be 2 dimensional.

ex. array:

```
15-3-2013 Arg1
15-3-2013 Arg2
15-3-2013 Arg1
15-3-2013 Arg1
16-3-2013 Arg3
16-3-2013 Arg3
16-3-2013 Arg1
```

Desired return for `=IleGier(E1:F10;"Arg1";"15-3-2013")` would be 3 (Date arg in this ex. might be passed wrong bcoz of ""), but it returns `#ARG` as long I use `UBound()` function.

Any tips?

Comment: FWIW, this can be done easily without a udf: `=COUNTIFS(F1:F10,"Arg1",E1:E10,"15-3-2013")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` being the second index, I guess you should use:

```
Do While i < UBound(Arr, 2)
```

Comment: Nah it doesnt change anything, the funny thing is, even
`Function tst(Arr As Variant) As Integer
    tst = UBound(Arr, 2)
End Function`
returns #ARG too

Comment: @user1709804 It's because when you call `tst(E1:F10)`, Arr is not an array, it is a range. If you try: `Function tst(Arr As Variant) As Integer Dim a As Variant a = Arr tst = UBound(a, 2) End Function` you should get the expected result.

Comment: In other words you have two options: work with the range directly which has some methods to know its size or copy the range into an array as in my previous comment. The latter is generally more efficient.